# Drupal Print PDF module with Chinese characters

Tags: files

I'm using the Print PDF module, but cannot get Chinese characters to display. I have tried DOMPDF (which displays as ?????), and TCPDF (which displays rectangles). I have tried changing all the settings (Use dompdf's Unicode Mode, dejavusans font etc...) but nothing works. What could I be missing?

I have set up mbstring in my php.ini as follows:

mbstring.detect_order . . . . . . . . . . . . .auto

mbstring.encoding_translation . . . . . . . .On

mbstring.http_input . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .auto

mbstring.http_output . . . . . . . . . . . . . .UTF-8

mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes . .text/|application/xhtml+xml

mbstring.internal_encoding . . . . . . . . . .UTF-8

mbstring.language . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .Neutral

mbstring.strict_detection . . . . . . . . . . .Off

mbstring.substitute_character . . . . . . . .no value

EDIT: It seems that I need to add the Firefly Sung font for this to work, but I still can't figure out how with respect to Drupal. Also - it seems you can only set one font for the entire site - not one font per language, which is what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I sort of solved it by using @font-face directly in the template file. Not the ideal solution, but it's working.